# find() based on conditions in multiple HABTM relations

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, conditional-statements, has-and-belongs-to-many, multiple-conditions

I'm working with CakePHP 2.1
Let's state I have the following models and relations:
`Posts` belongsTo `Edition`
`Posts` HABTM `Editors`
`Posts` HABTM `Tags`

I'm reasoning from the `PostsController` and I would like to find all `Posts` belonging to a certain `Edition`, and that `Editor.id=55` is related and `Tag.id=33` is related.

I have found many examples where finding `Posts` based on a condition over a HABTM relation is done by 'reversing' the find direction and reason from the `Editor`.

```
$this->Editor->find('all',
    array(
        'conditions'=>array('Editor.id'=>55),
        'contain'=>array('Post')
    )
);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work here, because there are multiple HABTM relations that I would like to put a condition on.

Also using `contain` does not work since it only cuts off a branch (`editors`) but does not help filtering it's parent (`posts`).

How do I solve this?
Do I maybe need to resort to ad hoc joins? And if so, could someone explain me roughly what approach to take?

**Edit:**
Some pseudo code in order to illustrate what I want to achieve:

```
$this->Post->find('all',
    array('conditions'=>array(
            'Edition.id'=>4,
             // start pseudo code
            'Post.Editor' => 'has at least one related editor with id=55',
            'Post.Tag' => 'has at least one related tag with id=33',
        )
    )
);
```

kind regards,
Bart

**Edit Solution:**
Following @RichardAtHome I created the solution below. Not (yet) employing multiple join conditions, but that appeared not to be necessary:

```
// Paginate over Cards that belong to current Subscription (belongsTo) AND the User is related to as an Editor (HABTM)
$this->paginate = array(
    'fields' => array('id','title','workingtitle','attachment_count','subscription_id'),
    'joins' => array(
        // create Editor-join
        array(
            'table' => 'cards_users',
            'alias' => 'Editor',
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Editor.card_id = Card.id'
            )
        ), 
        array( 
            'table' => 'users', 
            'alias' => 'User', 
            'type' => 'left',
            'conditions'=> array( 
                'User.id = Editor.user_id'
            ) 
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'OR' => array(
            // is Card in current subscription? (straightforward condition)
            array('Card.subscription_id',$subscription_id),
            // is current User assigned as Editor? (condition works with join above)
            array('User.id' => $user['id'])
        )
    ),
    'limit' => 10
);
```

Comment: What you actually want? Give some rough figure of code you want.

Comment: @arun-jain I've added some pseudo code, does that clarify enough?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this type of query, I usually find it easiest to construct the joins myself as cake won't join, it will perform multiple queries instead (select matching rows from table a, then fetch matching rows from table b).

Your query needs to look something like this:

```
$this->Post->find('all',
    array(
        'conditions'=>array('Post.edition_id'=>4),
        'joins'=>array(
            array(
                'type'=>'inner',
                'table'=>'posts_editors',
                'alias'=>'PostsEditor',
                'conditions'=>array(
                    'PostsEditor.post_id = Post.id',
                    'PostsEditor.editor_id'=>55 // your criteia for editor id=55
                )
            ),
            array(
                'type'=>'inner',
                'table'='posts_tags',
                'alias'=>'PostsTag',
                'conditions'=>array(
                    'PostsTag.post_id = Post.id',
                    'PostsTag.tag_id'=>33 // your criteria for tag id = 33
                )

            )
        )
    )
);
```

Check the SQL that's output to see what this query is actually doing behind the scenes.

Comment: @RichardAtHome

Hey Richard, you seem to know your stuff when it comes to joins.  Could you look at this rather annoying, but similar issue I have?

-- [Go to the Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688076/unable-to-achieve-results-needed-when-using-joins-in-modelfind) --

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$this->Post->find('all',
        array('conditions'=>array(
                'Edition.id'=>4,
                'Editor.id' => '55',
                'Tag.id' => '33',
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: Trying only the 'Editor.id' condition I get the error: `Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Editor.id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: `public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Editor' => array(
   'className' => 'User',
   'joinTable' => 'cards_users',
   'foreignKey' => 'card_id',
   'associationForeignKey' => 'user_id',
   'unique' => 'keepExisting',
   // only users belonging to the current Subscription AND having a 'Editor' or 'ChiefEditor' status are eligible
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => '',
   'order' => '',
   'limit' => '',
   'offset' => '',
   'finderQuery' => '',
   'deleteQuery' => '',
   'insertQuery' => ''
  )`

Comment: OK. Then add before the find() $this->Post->recursive=1;

Comment: How is that going to solve `Column not found`? At best it only restricts available information.

Comment: Thanks, I've added it. Unfortunately it did not work out. I raised the recursion level to 6 which did not make a difference either. I suspected I had to use joins and @richardathome below seems to confirm that. I'll try out his approach.

Comment: set $this->Post->recursive = 1; to overcome SQL Error